How to use map in this situation instead of switch
i want this to be mapping instead of hard coding the cases
const wCategory = () => {
        switch (categoryhovered) {
            case 1:
                return <SalePriceCtg />
            case 2:
                return <ArticlesCtg />
            default:
                return <div>smth3</div>
        }
    }

i cant map the cases so im searching for a better way to do it

Mapping makes use of an array; how would you envision using map for this?

Here is a way to use an object instead of a switch statement:
const wCategory = () => {
    const categories = {
        1: <SalePriceCtg />,
        2: <ArticlesCtg />,
        default: <div>smth3</div>
    };

    return categories[categoryhovered] || categories.default;
};


this worked but I don't want to use numbers so that if i add more categories it would handle those too

You can use an object to map the cases instead of hardcoding them with a switch statement
const categoryMap = {
1: SalePriceCtg,
2: ArticlesCtg,
// add more cases here
};

const wCategory = () => {
const Component = categoryMap[categoryhovered];
return Component ? <Component /> : <div>smth3</div>;
};

